# Difference table for interpolation

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

For calculating divided (fraction) difference table for interpolating the points $(x_i, f_i)$, $i=1,2,...,n$; by using a polynomial with degree lower or equal to $n$, $n(n-1)/2$ fraction was used.

I think this sentence is false and $n(n+1)/2$ is needed. Am I right? any hint or idea would highly appreciated. My instructor use following example to prove it:

[image]

Comment: There are $5$ points, and $10$ divided differences, or $(5\times4)/2$.

Comment: Dear @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, yes, it means n(n-1) / 2.  but i think it's false.

Comment: What would be the other $n$ ones?

Comment: Dear @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, i means n(n+1) / 2.

Comment: Yes, $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=n$. So where are the other $n$ ones you think are necessary?

Comment: Dear @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, i couldn't understand what did you say?

Comment: Dear @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, i think if i start from 0 there is n(n+1)/2 and if i start from 1 there is n(n-1)/2? am i right?

Comment: $n$ is the number of points. If you start from index $i=0$ and there are $n$ points, the last has index $i=n-1$, and there are still $n(n-1)/2$ divided differences, since there are still $n$ points.

Comment: Dear @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, you means the last answer is n(n-1) / 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of [forward difference operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) in a divided difference table forms an **arithmetic series** (the sum of the members of a finite [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)). For $n$ points, the number of forward difference operators, i.e. the number of $\Delta_i^j$ 's; as seen in the divided difference table is
$$
1+2+3+\cdots+(n-1)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k}
$$
For an arithmetic series $a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_m$ with $m$ terms we have
$$
a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_m=\sum_{k=a_1}^{a_m}{k}=\frac{m(a_1+a_m)}{2}
$$
where $a_1$ is the initial term of an arithmetic progression and $a_m$ is the $m$th term of the sequence. Here we have $m=n-1$ terms, $a_1=1$ and $a_m=n-1$. Now mix all the ingredients
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k}=\frac{(n-1)\left(1+(n-1)\right)}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$

---

**In reply to the comment:**

If we start from zero then you have $n+1$ points $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$, not $n$ points that implies $a_1=1$, $m=n$ and $a_m=n$. Thus
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k}=1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
**But be careful.** In the above statement $n$ is not the number of points. It is the index of $x_n$. The number of points is $n+1$. As @Jean-ClaudeArbaut said, there are still $n(n−1)/2$ forward difference operators (be careful not to confuse this $n$ with the index of $x_n$. For this, it is good to write $N(N-1)/2$ where $N$ is the number of points) **if we don't pay attention to the index of $x_n$ and just count the points**.

For example for the following table
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
i & x_i & f_i & \Delta f_i & \Delta^2f_i & \Delta^3f_i & \Delta^4f_i\\
\hline
0 & x_0 & f_0 & \Delta f_0 & \Delta^2f_0 & \Delta^3f_0 & \Delta^4f_0\\
1 & x_1 & f_1 & \Delta f_1 & \Delta^2f_1 & \Delta^3f_1 & \\
2 & x_2 & f_2 & \Delta f_2 & \Delta^2f_2 & \\
3 & x_3 & f_3 & \Delta f_3 & \\
4 & x_4 & f_4 & \\
\end{array}
$$
we have five points. Thus
$$
\text{Number of } \Delta_i^j \text{'s} = \frac{N(N-1)}{2}=\frac{5(5-1)}{2}=10
$$
If you like to use the index of the last point $x_4$, you can use
$$
\text{Number of } \Delta_i^j \text{'s} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{4(4+1)}{2}=10
$$
Note you cannot use $n(n+1)/2$ if we start from one
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
i & x_i & f_i & \Delta f_i & \Delta^2f_i & \Delta^3f_i & \Delta^4f_i\\
\hline
1 & x_1 & f_1 & \Delta f_1 & \Delta^2f_1 & \Delta^3f_1 & \Delta^4f_1\\
2 & x_2 & f_2 & \Delta f_2 & \Delta^2f_2 & \Delta^3f_2 & \\
3 & x_3 & f_3 & \Delta f_3 & \Delta^2f_3 & \\
4 & x_4 & f_4 & \Delta f_4 & \\
5 & x_5 & f_5 & \\
\end{array}
$$
Since 
$$
\text{Number of } \Delta_i^j \text{'s} = \frac{N(N-1)}{2}=\frac{5(5-1)}{2}=10
$$
but
$$
\text{Number of } \Delta_i^j \text{'s} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{5(5+1)}{2}=15
$$
It is just playing with indices.

Comment: Dear user..., if i start from 0, i.e i=0,1,...,n this sum up to n(n+1)/2?

Comment: Dear @MinaSoli I edited my post.